# add input values to html attributes on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this:

```
<input type="text" name="field1" id="firstField">
<input type="text" name="field2" id="secondField">
<button name="submitButton" data-parameter="">Click</button>
```

When you click on the button, an EventListener (`jQuery.on`) calls a function `jQuery.ajax()` to load another page where the data gets processed.

the `data-parameter` attribute is the data for `$_POST`.

So, `data-parameter="name1=test"` is `$_POST["name1"]` with a value `test`

But how do I get the values of the `input`-fields into this attribute?

And I have more than one form like this. Some contain more fields, some less.

Comment: I don't get what you means. What's your expected result?

Comment: FYI, IDs must be unique.

Comment: and if `[name="field1"]`, why is there also a `id="firstField"` attribute?

Comment: 1.I want that the value of field1 and field2 go into the `data-parameter` attribute of the button. Because this attribute sets the parameter for the data, sent by $.ajax()


2.sorry, the second id was a typo. I'll correct this.


3.I nearly always add a `id` to  elements

Answer (score 1):

```
$('form button[name="submitButton"]').click(function(){    
  $(this).data('parameter',$(this).closest('form').serialize());
}
```

Comment: thanks, this could work. But if I have multiple forms on one page, do I have to make this for every form I have? Or is it possible to select the `form-element` in whic the button you have clicked on is? So that you don't need to know the exact name/id of the form? Because then, you could do a EventListener for all buttons with the class `.submitButton`. I hope you understand what I mean. It's difficult to explain

Comment: i updated the code now u dont need the form name, and if there is only 1 button in the form u dont even need the buttons name too just use $('form button') or $('form button[type="submit"]') and set the buttons type to submit

Answer (score 1):

i don't know why cant you just send the data from those input fields directly to the $ajax().

Anyway a generalized code to get all data and to place it in on the data-parameter would be..
step 1: First you need a form or div tag binding all the necessary input fields and a button.
step 2: I expect the variable name used in the url post method is same as the input field name, so the just the value changes. And also as u said if the no. of fields changes, its ok. even though u can use this piece of code.
Step 3: i am using onclick event of the button to capture all data. And only after that u should run the code to send via $_POST
Step 4: Change the tags #yourFormID,#buttonID as per use.

```
var data-parameter="";
$('#buttonID').click(function(){

  $('#yourFormID input[type=text]').each(function(){
     var data-parameter+=$(this).attr("name")+"="+$(this).val()+"&";
  });
  $('#buttonID').attr("data-parameter",data-parameter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to call var serializedFormData = $(yourform).serialize() and paste this data to your button $('[name=submitButton]').data('parameter', serializedFormData). You better provide a part of code to better understanding.